# Access to parent second child in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ho i can show clear-field when input is changed

```
<div class="small-12 columns">
    <input type="text" name="job_title" id="resume_title" class="required ui-autocomplete-input" maxlength="128">
    <span class="clear-field" style="display: none;"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand the relationship between title and your question. Do you have many input boxes with same id i.e. `resume_title` (which would be wrong), or you have multiple `clear-field` and you want to display the nearest one on the change in your input box?

By assuming you have just one textbox with the id `resume_title` and one span with class `clear-field`:

```
$(function(){
   $("#resume_title").change(function() {
    $(".clear-field").css({ display: "block" });
  });
});
```